# store an image in database

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an asp page. In asp page I have an image control. There is an image within the image control. I want to save this image in database.  In the database the particular field data type is image. How is it possible?

Comment: Why do you prefer database instead of file system?

Comment: Try to accept some answers for your questions. That will motivate others to answer your questions in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this article out: 
[Save and Retrieve Images from the Database using ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

**Example from the above article**

First of all you need to convert your image into bytes like this:

```
FileUpload img = (FileUpload)imgUpload;
Byte[] imgByte = null;
if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
{
    //To create a PostedFile
    HttpPostedFile File = imgUpload.PostedFile;
    //Create byte Array with file len
    imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
    //force the control to load data in array
    File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
}
```

Then you use `imgByte` as value when you add to your database.

Comment: The problem with this kind of code is it allocates a byte array the size of the file. It means 1) it will simply not work for big files and 2) for files bigger than 85k, it will hit the Large Object Heap (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) and therefore on the long run will not help garbage collection. I would prefer streaming mode but can't find any example on google. If anyone's interested, I can dig a bit :-)

Comment: @Simon, I aggree. You shouldn't be able to upload as big images as you like anyways, since that might chocke the server.

Comment: You seem dead set on this but I think it should be noted that while putting images in the database will make backup and perhaps version-ing easier, it would put more load on the database when loading stuff. This might cause some problems on high traffic pages. However if you do not foresee much crazy traffic into this then this should be fine =)

Comment: I guess one should save the file in a temp folder and then write to the DB. Will be much more manageable.